# Applying conditional label opacity in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, conditional, transparency-opacity

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover.

I've got one layer with all Spanish provinces (`provincias`) and, on top of it, several layers with the regions (`AND`, `ARA`, `AST`...). Each province pertains to one region and each region may contain one or more provinces.

I want to label the `provincias` layer with different opacity, depending on whether their region layer is visible or not. Here is where I try to set the differential label opacity

[image]

And this is the result I intend to achieve (layer `AND`, visible)

[image]

And I've tried the following code, without success:

```sql
case
   when (overlay_within('AND') and is_layer_visible('AND')) then 50 
   when (overlay_within('ARA') and is_layer_visible('ARA')) then 50
   [...]
   else 20
end
```

It only works with the first region, and this is what happens when I make visible the next one (`ARA`)

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, many things are uncelar to me: Where do you apply the expression? What does not work? You use this in an atlas - or what else do you mean with "active region layer"? What is the order of your layers - which one is on top?

Comment: Could you remove `=1` and try again?

Comment: Edited and tried the suggestion of @Kazuhito. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks Jesús Pinilla for the update. What if you click on `Refresh` button after switching the visible layer?

Comment: I have, but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click data driven override for label opacity and select `Assistant`. Add the following expression, set `values from/to` to 0 and 1, and `Opacity from / to` to the opacity values you like (see screenshot at the bottom).

The expression works like this:

1. The idea is to first get an array of all layers with `@layer_ids` (line 3)
2. Then for each of these layer (using `array_foreach`, line 2) check if (line 4) it is visible (line 5) and if so, return it's name (line 6), otherwise an empty string (line 7).
3. Use `array_contains` (line 1) to check if the resulting array from step 2 contains a region's layer name that corresponds to the value of the attribute field `"region"` (2nd last line) in the provinces layer. In this case, the result is 1, otherwise 0.

The final expression looks like:

```
array_contains(
    array_foreach (
        @layer_ids,
        if (
            is_layer_visible( @element),
            layer_property( @element, 'name'),
            ''
        )
    ), 
    "region"
)
```

Replace `region` in the second last line with the name you use as fieldname in the provinces layer. Be sure these values correspond to the names of the layers (as can be seen on the screenshot).

*By the way: it is always a good idea to provide the data + project file you work with, at least dummy data. This saves time for you as well as the one answering (time to set up a testing project and time adapting the answer to the values and names you use in your project).*

[image]